# different total number of columns in add_header_above from kable

Tags: r, kableextra

I am using kableExtra to format tables in rmarkdown. In one of my dataframes I am obtaining a strange result...

```
ncol(Selected)
Selected%>%
kable("html",format.args = list(decimal.mark = ".", big.mark = ","),caption = "Variables description  and data cleaning and treatment summary") %>%
add_header_above(c(" " = 2, "Kolmogorov-Smirnov" = 2, "Kruskall-Wallis" = 2, "Wilcoxon  Test"= 2)) %>%
kable_styling()
```

The object Selected is a dataframe, with dimension (256;8)...

I got this:

```
[1] 8
Error in htmlTable_add_header_above(kable_input, header, bold, italic, : The new header row you provided has a different total number of columns with the original kable output.
```

What is wrong? By ncol, I confirmed the object Selected has 8 columns... 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't expect any specific advice without providing [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi, David, thank you for giving attention to my question. I agree that this question does not have a minimal reproducible example as I did not make available the data frame. Could you tell me how can I do this? I tried when I was writing the question, but I was not able to figure out...

Comment: I think I figure out the reason for the error message... while trying to better describe the dataframe (as I was not able to append it), I noticed that this data frame has rownames, whereas others do not... I tried to change the   add_header_above(c(" " = 2... to add_header_above(c(" " = 3... and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data frame has row names. The kable command counts row names as the column. Counting this, it worked.

```
Selected%>%
kable("html",format.args = list(decimal.mark = ".", big.mark = ","),caption = "Variables description  and data cleaning and treatment summary") %>%
add_header_above(c(" " = 3, "Kolmogorov-Smirnov" = 2, "Kruskall-Wallis" = 2, "Wilcoxon  Test"= 2)) %>%
kable_styling()
```